# A homeomorphism from the integers with the digital line topology to the natural numbers with a specific equivalent topology defined

Tags: general-topology

Consider a homeomorphism from the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology to the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ with an equivalent topology defined by:
$$
h: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \ by\ h(z)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{1l}
            1 & \quad z=0\\
            2z & \quad z>0 \\
           1-2z & \quad z<0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
For completeness, the inverse function is 
$$
h^{-1}(n)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{1l}
            0 & \quad n=1\\
            n/2 & \quad n=even \\
           (1-n)/2 & \quad n=odd
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I believe several open sets in the equivalent topology on $\mathbb{N}$ are $\{1,2,3\}$,$\{3,5,7\}$, $\{4,6,8\}$.

Alternatively, $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{6,7,10\}$ are not open because their pre-image, $\{2,-1,2\}$ and $\{3,-3,4\}$ respectively are not open on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,5,7\}$ are the images of $\{-1,0,1\}$ and $\{-3,-2,-1\}$, respectively, so they are indeed open in the transferred topology on $\Bbb N$. $\{4,6,8\}$, however, is the image of $\{2,3,4\}$, which is not open in $\Bbb Z$, since it does not contain a nbhd of either $2$ or $3$, so so it’s not an open set in $\Bbb N$. $\{6,8,10\}$, on the other hand, is open in $\Bbb N$, since it’s the image of the open set $\{3,4,5\}$ in $\Bbb Z$.

$\{2,3,4\}$ is the image of $\{-1,1,2\}$, not $\{2,-1,2\}$, but I expect that that error was just a typo. As you say, it’s not open, because $\{-1,1,2\}$ does not contain a nbhd of $2$. The preimage of $\{6,7,10\}$ is $\{-3,3,5\}$, not $\{-3,3,4\}$, so it *is* open: the points $-3,3$, and $5$ are all isolated in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ah thanks- sorry about the typos and good explanation for $\{6,7,10\}$ - makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Learner: You’re welcome!